# Difference between "There is to be" "there has to be"

Tags: there-is, deontic-vs-epistemic, periphrastic-modals

"There is to be an urgent ministerial review of language learning."

Does this mean that the review is going to take place, or does this mean that there should be a review? I am a little clueless.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score 2):

"There is to be" seems to imply that some event is going to take place but tends towards speculation, it should happen, it's scheduled.

"There has to be" strongly references an idea of something that MUST happen, it is an imperative statement but can also be interpreted as an expression to declare hope.